# Headless/Decoupled CMS suggestions

Tags: content-management-system, headless

I am here for your suggestions regarding headless/decoupled CMS. We fully developed our web application in java as backend and backboneJs as front end. We using REST calls to connect backend server.

Marketing team needed an admin panel to add blogs, landing pages, e.t.c. SO, we need an API based CMS with admin panel, Where our marketing team add blogs, landing pages e.t.c and we call the API's in our custom website and show the added data from healess CMS to our website.

We are need of CMS now. Please suggest me which will be the best CMS to use in our current tech stack?

We need any REST API Based CMS, need to create our own db tables from their admin panel, can have flexible to use.

I tried https://directus.io .But, still wanna try and select in those. We need to create blogs, landing pages, sliders in static pages, HTML editors kind of stuff, response in JSON from API e.t.c Please help em in choosing a good CMS

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [directus](http://getdirectus.com). It's purely headless CMS and you can write webhooks, Call API's e.t.c

Minimum requirements:

> NGINX or Apache Server, PHP 5.5+, MySQL
>   5.2+, PDO_MySQL, Mod_Rewrite, CURL, FileInfo, GD Library, and mcrypt

Directus is built with:

> Backbone.js, Underscore, Require.js, Zend DB,
>   Slim, Handlebars, jQuery, Moment.js, Sortable.js, Noty, and SASS.

Loved it. You guys will too; try it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever try [Crafter CMS](http://craftersoftware.com/). 
It's a very scalable lightweight CMS with Java Backend.
It's very very flexible and you can define a well structured RESTful API for your needs. As for the front end you can pretty much use any Javascript Framework you might need, most of the times I have use Angular Js with no problem.
It also use Apache Solr as a very powerfull search engine. I being working with it for quite a bit now and everything you need is very easy to do.

Comment: Thanks, But we already developed our whole website in Java(vertx framework) as backend and backboneJS as front end. Now we need an admin panel to add blogs, pages by marketing team. We just call the API's to fetch the data .. is this possible with this?

Comment: No that would be difficult with this software.

Comment: oh then it won't fit for me then :( .. any other headless CMS which u know

Comment: Crafter would make a great fit even with the Vertx framework.  Crafter CMS can operate as a 100% headless CMS.  Just define the types you need BLOG, PAGE, etc.  Then define API urls and JSON structures you want the content to return in and VOILA! your Vertex/backbone app will have a completely dynamic content back end that's easy for your admins to add content to any time they want. 

https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms

Here's a relevant article on DZONE. The concepts are exactly the same for backbone:
https://dzone.com/articles/building-angular2-single-page-applications-with-cr

Comment: +1 for Crafter. If you download the latest version from source, from github, following the installation instructions from https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms you'll even see several headless "blueprints", which are like sample sites from which to build yours.

Comment: There's blueprints for a headless blog and for a headless store, and you can probably build any other headless site you can think of. And since it uses Java or Groovy, you and you dev teammates will feel right at home

Comment: Oh!  I am sorry, I misunderstood your response.  Russ is correct!

Answer (score -1):

If you prefer the headless CMS to be more on the simple side, to keep your development costs down, then you could try https://www.headlesscontentmanagement.com/ it's free to use, but is more designed around storing HTML content than JSON objects.